# How to forward-search-history with the reverse-i-search command (ctrl+r)?

Tags: command-line

In the readline manual

```
# man readline
```

The following describes how to search backward and forward.

```
reverse-search-history (C-r)
Search backward starting at the current line and moving `up' through the history as necessary.  This is an incremental search.

forward-search-history (C-s)
Search forward starting at the current line and moving `down' through the  history  as  necessary.   This  is  an  incremental search.
```

When I hit ctrl+r and type "apt-get", I'm able to do a reverse-search-history by continually tapping ctrl+r.  But then I tap ctrl+s and the terminal does not go forwards.  Am I doing something incorrect?

Also what key does the Meta prefix "M-" represent?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The sequence `C-s` is taken from the terminal driver, as you can see from

```
stty -a | grep '\^S'
```

To free up the sequence for use by readline, set the stop terminal sequence to some other sequence, as for example

```
stty stop ^J
```

or remove it altogether with

```
stty stop undef
```

After that `C-s` would work in the given terminal.

Set it in `~/.bashrc` to make it work in every terminal.

The `M-` sequence means the <kbd>Alt</kbd> key, as already noted.

Comment: ^J is a good choice since for `stop`, it's not used for anything else

Answer (score 3):

In addition to assigning a different TTY 'stop' char as suggested above, you can remove it entirely if you don't plan to use it (I tend not to), like this:

```
$ stty stop undef
```

Then readline can use control-s for forward search and you won't get any strange behavior due to a new stop char being added.

Answer (score 1):

forward-search-history (C-s) doesn't work (though it is in the man page).

'M-' represents the Alt key modifier.

Comment: Not correct the `C-s` part, see my answer.

Answer (score 1):

To switch forward when using reverse search (with Ctrl-R command):

1. Open your .bashrc file:

   ```
   sudo gedit ~/.bashrc
   ```
2. add this line (the letter "f" can be replaced with another not yet used by the system)

   ```
   bind '"\C-f": forward-search-history'
   ```
3. Close your file and update your .bashrc (or open another terminal) with the command:

   ```
   source ~/.bashrc
   ```

   or

   ```
   . ~/.bashrc
   ```

Now you can move forward in the history with the shortcut <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>f</kbd>

Working on Ubuntu 18.04 LTS

Answer (score 0):

Please do not use:

```
stty stop ^J
```

but

```
stty stop ^P
```

or anything else, as `^J` makes big problems with ssh. (I do not know why anyway.)
After I logged in <kbd>Enter</kbd> and backslash were not working. 
or I had to type:

```
stty sane 
export TERM=linux
```

before I wanted to type

```
ssh root@192...
```

so

```
stty stop ^P
```

solved both problems at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

You can disable XON/XOFF flow control:

```
stty -ixon
```

in your *~/.profile* or similar, then Ctrl+S will be recognized.

[Example](//github.com/svnpenn/dotfiles/blob/3298fa4/shell/.profile#L14)

Answer (score 0):

Note that I had used

```
stty stop ^J
stty -ixoff
```

in .bashrc to enable forward search and disable the annoying "Output has been suspended by pressing Ctrl+S. Press Ctrl+Q to resume" message in Konsole when ctrl+s was pressed, but both commands individually broke the Konsole integration in Dolphin (the "F4" shortcut) in the way that I had to do ctrl+c two times to get it to even work, and the automatic "cd" commands where not being injected when graphically navigating.

So I now prefer:

```
stty stop undef
stty -ixon
```

It has the same effect, an all seems to work as expected ;)